# Flip or reverse columns in numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I want to flip the first and second values of arrays in an array. A naive solution is to loop through the array. What is the right way of doing this?

```
import numpy as np
contour = np.array([[1, 4],
                    [3, 2]])

flipped_contour = np.empty((0,2))
for point in contour:
    x_y_fipped = np.array([point[1], point[0]])
    flipped_contour = np.vstack((flipped_contour, x_y_fipped))

print(flipped_contour)

[[4. 1.]
[2. 3.]]
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use the aptly named `np.flip`:

```
np.flip(contour, axis=1)
```

Or,

```
np.fliplr(contour)
```

```
array([[4, 1],
       [2, 3]])
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use `numpy` [indexing](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/arrays.indexing.html):

```
contour[:, ::-1]
```

Answer (score 7):

In addition to [COLDSPEED's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49545765/9565387), if we only want to swap the first and second column only, not to flip the entire array:

```
contour[:, :2] = contour[:, 1::-1]
```

Here `contour[:, 1::-1]` is the array formed by first two columns of the array `contour`, in the reverse order. It then is assigned to the first two columns (`contour[:, :2]`). Now the first two column are swapped.

In general, to swap the `i`th and `j`th columns, do the following:

```
contour[:, [i, j]] = contour[:, [j, i]]
```

Comment: That should be `contour[:, :2] = contour[:, 1::-1]`, shouldn't it?

Answer (score 3):

Here are two non-inplace ways of swapping the first two columns:

```
>>> a = np.arange(15).reshape(3, 5)
>>> a[:, np.r_[1:-1:-1, 2:5]]
array([[ 1,  0,  2,  3,  4],
       [ 6,  5,  7,  8,  9],
       [11, 10, 12, 13, 14]])
```

or

```
>>> np.c_[a[:, 1::-1], a[:, 2:]]
array([[ 1,  0,  2,  3,  4],
       [ 6,  5,  7,  8,  9],
       [11, 10, 12, 13, 14]])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> your_array[indices_to_flip] = np.flip(your_array[indices_to_flip], axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way would be using [permutation matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation_matrix)

```
import numpy as np

contour = np.array([[1, 4],
                [3, 2]])

P = np.array([[0, 1],
         [1, 0]])#permutation matrix that will 
                 #swap column 1 with column 2 if right multiplied

contour = contour @ P
print(contour)
```

Output:

```
array([[4, 1],
   [2, 3]])
```